# $S1 = 1 + {x^3 \over 3!} + {x^6 \over 6!} + ...$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

In one of my lecturer's problem sheets we were asked to evaluate the following sums:
$$S1 = 1 + {x^3 \over 3!} + {x^6 \over 6!} + \dots $$
$$S2 = {x^1 \over 1!} +{x^4 \over 4!} +{x^7 \over 7!} + \dots$$
$$S3 = {x^2 \over 2!} +{x^5 \over 5!} +{x^8 \over 8!} + \dots$$

In case it's relevant, we were previously required to solve $z^3 -1 =0$, which is simple. And show that if ω is one of the complex roots of the above equation, $ω^2 + ω +1 = 0$.

How would one go about solving these sums? Is there an obvious method which I am missing?

Comment: Hint:  Write out the power series for $\sum e^{\omega_i x}$ Where the sum covers the three cube roots of $1$.

Comment: Another possible approach if you prefer to solve ODEs: from the power series for $e^x$ we see that $S_1 + S_2 + S_3 = e^x$. We further see that $S_3'' = S_1$ and $S_2' = S_1$ so $S_1$ satisfy the ODE $S_1'' + S_1' + S_1 = e^x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: We have 
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\cdots$$ and 
$$e^{\omega x}=1+\omega x+\frac{1}{2!}\omega^2 x^2+\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\cdots$$ and $$e^{\omega^2 x}=1+\omega^2 x+\frac{1}{2!}\omega x^2+\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\cdots.$$

Add.  After finding $S_1(x)$ we can get the others by differentiating.

Comment: Why is that? I imaged we would get $e^{ω^2 x} = 1+ ω^2 x+ {1 \over 2!} ω^4 x^2+ {1 \over 3!} ω^6 x^3+ \dots$. Edit: Got it -> ω^3 = 1

Comment: Don't you mean integrating?

Comment: I mean differentiating term by term. Integrating will also work.